# Is there any possible way to identify whether a image file was converted to word file through OCR or not

Tags: ocr

Is there any possible way to identify whether a image file was converted to word file through OCR or not...when all the errors in converted file was rectified by comparing the original image file and rectified everything which is visible...is there any hidden signs for conversion..please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Generally  No, but the converter or tool (using which ocr is dont) may store some info about itself try to find it.